# Error while deploying mean stack application in heroku

Tags: heroku, mongoose, runtime-error, mean-stack

I have tried deploying mean stack application to Heroku, but when I visit the URL:

https://rocky-coast-36852.herokuapp.com/%20deployed%20to%20Heroku

It's showing the error:

```
Cannot GET /%20deployed%20to%20Heroku
```

Also while trying to connect to mongoose database it showing the error:

```
error in database connectonMongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
(node:42332) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
```

Here is my GitHub link:

https://github.com/saisreereddy/MyFirstApp

Can someone please identify where I doing wrong?
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This line would seem to be the cause of your problem:

`mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/contactlistapp');`

Presumably, your database is not running on your Heroku dynos and you're using a Heroku hosted database add-on, like MLab. (If not, provisioning a Mongo add-on is the first step in your solution.) When this add-on is added to your application, it will set an environment variable like `DATABASE_URL` (refer to add-on documentation), which will contain the database url, username, password, etc.

You'll want to change that line above in app.js to pull that value from the environment using something like `mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL);`, which should *just work* on Heroku.

Now, you'll also need to set that environment variable locally, using the value you currently have hardcoded in app.js. I'd suggest using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to handle setting the local env vars. If you do use dotenv, be sure to add .env to your .gitignore file.